# I3C HDR-DDR write multi byte stream transfer issues

Tags: debugging, embedded, hardware

I am trying to develop a test code to check HDR-DDR write transfers for I3C bus interface on a proprietary IP (which I can't disclose here, unfortunately). Please see below the description of the problem.

Test scenario -
I have 2 devices, one as main controller or master (MC) and the other as secondary controller(SC) running on 1 MHz SCL. MC will issue a command to have I3C bus enter HDR and then issue a command to write the payload (in this case, few bytes of data). On the SC, an interrupt will be triggered once data has been received in the Rx FIFO of the SC. Lastly, SC will issue a command to read the data from the FIFO and validate.

Problem -
What I see is that if I transfer 2 bytes of data from MC to SC, everything works fine. Interrupt is triggered perfectly and data is validated.
Now when I transfer 3 or more bytes of data from MC to SC, I see that interrupt is never triggered. On the register level, I see that DDR Rx FIFO is shown as FULL somehow (which might be a cause for this issue).

What have I tried so far and didn't work -

1. Reduce the clock speed. Varied between 100 KHz to 1 MHz as I thought I might be clocking the data too fast.
2. Played around with drive strength of the GPIO's
3. Played around with adjusting the delays on the transfers.
4. Sending and receiving 1 byte of data at a time. To my surprise here, I could see that it works till 7 bytes and on the 8th byte, transfer fails again.

Not sure if there could be a limitation on the RTL logic of the FIFO's here. Seeking help and advice on the same.

Let me know if more information is required.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is going to be impossible to answer without details. In particular we'd need to know which microcontroller you are using and the relevant parts of the code. Add details to the question by editing.

Comment: I'm assuming this is pre-silicon, based on your talk about a potential limitation in the RTL.  If that's the case, you should be hitting up your hardware block designers and looking at what's going on in simulation.  These sound very much like the sort of things a first-pass implementation would have since a lot of hardware designers ignore the stuff outside their blocks until things blow up in integration.